# Does SSH key with type ecdsa-sk or ed25519-sk need passphrase?

Tags: ssh

OpenSSH 8.2 introduced new public key types "ecdsa-sk" and "ed25519-sk", and the key file contains a reference to the private key credential stored on the FIDO/U2F hardware. Should I still need enter a passphrase when create these types of SSH key? It's seems useless if one attacker get the private key file without FIDO/U2F hardware access.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, your ssh key would be useless without the hardware key, but what if he stole them together? eg he takes your laptop or your bag with the hardware key inside.

You can optionally add a passphrase so the attacker would need the private key, the hardware key, and something that only you know. If you like the extra layer of security or this ssh key gives access to the whole company, then a passphrase would be a great extra layer of security.